# Permission denied error for bitnami redis cluster tls connection using helm chart?

Tags: redis, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, redis-cluster

Recently have tried to deploy redis-cluster on kubernetes cluster using helm chart. I am following below links--
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis-cluster

For helm deployment have used values-production.yaml. the default deployment went successful and able to create three node redis cluster (three master and three slave).

I am checking on two things currently:

1. How to enable container logs, as per the official docs, it should be written in "/opt/bitnami/redis/logs" but haven't seen any logs here.

From the official docs got to know, that in redis.conf log file name should be mention but currently it is "" Empty string, not sure how to and where to pass log file so that it should come in redis.conf.

2. I have tried to enable tls as well.. Have generated the certificates mentioned as per the redis.io/tls official docs. After than I have created the secret key mentioned in bitnami/tls section and passed the certificates in secret key.

Then I have passed the secret key name and all the certificates in values-production.yaml, then deployed the helm chart and it was giving me permission denied error msg.. For libfile.Sh in line number 37...

When I have checked the pod status,  out of 6 pods three pods are in running 2/2 state and 3 pods in 1/2 crash loopback off state.

After logging on running pod able to verify that certificates got placed at location "/opt/bitnami/redis/certs/", and changes also got reflected in redis.conf file for the certificates...

Pls let me know how to make any configuration changes in redis.conf  file using bitnami redis helm chart and how to resolve above two issue??

My understanding is for any redis.conf related changes, I have  to pass values in values-production.yaml file... Pls let me know on this..thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here

My first recommendation for you is to open an issue at https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues if you are struggling with the Redis Cluster chart.

Regarding the logs, as it's mentioned at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-cluster#logging:

> The Bitnami Redis-Cluster Docker image sends the container logs to stdout

Therefore, you can simply access the logs by running (substitute "POD_NAME" with the actual name of any of you Redis pods):

```html
kubectl logs POD_NAME
```

Finally, with respect to the TLS configuration, I guess you're following [this guide](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis-cluster#securing-traffic-using-tls) right?